# Is it possible to use Socket.io with NuxtJs?

Tags: socket.io, nuxt.js

I want to use socket.io in my Nuxtjs. Is it possible?

I tried [this tutorial](https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-socketio/) but I am getting the following error:

```
These dependencies were not found:

* fs in ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
* uws in ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
```

Comment: which version of Node.js do you use? then can you share the list of deps in your "package.json" file ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The better way to play with Nuxt.js + Socket.io is to follow this official example from core-team: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/with-sockets

Comment: Hi, I hope I'm not too late to the party but I decided to modularize that example, make it a bit more "npm-friendly" and push to the npm repo. I just authored [nuxt-socket-io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-socket-io) The idea is: just npm install it, configure sockets in nuxt.config, and just use it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. @RichS

Answer (score 5):

***Updated answer with linked example on GitHub***

I would suggest to use the **[`nuxt-socket-io` module](https://nuxt-socket-io.netlify.app)**. It is really easy to [set up](https://nuxt-socket-io.netlify.app/installation) and has a [nice documentation](https://nuxt-socket-io.netlify.app/usage).

I built [this litte demo example](https://github.com/NeonMika/nuxt-socket-io-demo) and I will list the steps that I took to build it (this is even a bit more thorough than the [Setup section](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-socket-io) of the npm package):

1. Add nuxt-socket-io dependency to your project:

   `yarn add nuxt-socket-io # or npm install nuxt-socket-io`
2. (If you already have a socket.io server you can skip this part)

   Add following line to your `nuxt.config.js` file: `serverMiddleware: [ "~/serverMiddleware/socket-io-server.js" ]` (Please do not mix up serverMiddleware with middleware, this are two different things)

   Then, create the file `./serverMiddleware/socket-io-server.js` where you can implement your socket.io *server*.

   ```js
   // This file is executed once when the server is started

   // Setup a socket.io server on port 3001 that has CORS disabled
   // (do not set this to port 3000 as port 3000 is where
   // the nuxt dev server serves your nuxt application)
   const io = require("socket.io")(3001, {
     cors: {
       // No CORS at all
       origin: '*',
     }
   });

   var i = 0;
   // Broadcast "tick" event every second
   // Or do whatever you want with io ;)
   setInterval(() => {
     i++;
     io.emit("tick", i);
   }, 1000);

   // Since we are a serverMiddleware, we have to return a handler,
   // even if this it does nothing
   export default function (req, res, next) {
     next()
   }
   ```
3. (If you already have Vuex set up, you can skip this)

   Add following empty Vuex store, i.e., create the file `./store/index.js`, since the module needs Vuex set up.

   ```js
   export const state = () => ({})
   ```
4. Add nuxt-socket-io to the modules section of `nuxt.config.js`, this will enable socket-io client:

   ```js
   {
     modules: [
       'nuxt-socket-io',
     ],
     // socket.io configuration
     io: {
     // we could have multiple sockets that we identify with names
     // one of these sockets may have set "default" to true
       sockets: [{
         default: true, // make this the default socket
         name: 'main', // give it a name that we can later use to choose this socket in the .vue file
         url: 'http://localhost:3001' // URL wherever your socket IO server runs
       }]
     },
   }
   ```
5. Use it in your components:

   ```js
   {
     data() {
       return {
         latestTickId: 0,
       };
     },
     mounted() {
       const vm = this;

       // use "main" socket defined in nuxt.config.js
       vm.socket = this.$nuxtSocket({
         name: "main" // select "main" socket from nuxt.config.js - we could also skip this because "main" is the default socket
       });

       vm.socket.on("tick", (tickId) => {
         vm.latestTickId = tickId;
       });
     },
   }
   ```
6. Run it with `npm run dev` and enjoy your tick events :)

[image]

Comment: Hi @Markus
I tried it but doesn't work, may I missed server.js ? please could you set all steps ? thanks

Comment: upvoted! could you kindly share what your server file looks like?

Comment: Hello @BKF. My original answer did not include any server code. I updated my answer to show the complete client *and* server side.

Comment: Hello @PirateApp. I did not have access to the code anymore, but I used my Saturday to set up the following demo project and updated the answer accordingly. Hope this helps! https://github.com/NeonMika/nuxt-socket-io-demo

Answer (score 3):

## Nuxt + socket.io

For me worked:

1. Create project as nodejs app (not static page);
2. Install socket.io `npm i socket.io`;
3. Add serverMiddleware section to `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  ...,
  serverMiddleware: [
    {path: '/ws', handler: '~/api/srv.js'},
  ],
}
```

4. Create middleware `/app/srv.js`:

```js
const app = require('express')()
const socket = require('socket.io')
let server = null
let io = null

app.all('/init', (req, res) => {
  if (!server) {
    server = res.connection.server
    io = socket(server)

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
      console.log('Made socket connection');

      socket.on('msg', msg => {
        console.log('Recived: ' + msg)

        setTimeout(() => {
          socket.emit('msg', `Response to: ${msg}`)
        }, 1000)
      })

      socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('disconnected'))
    })
  }

  res.json({ msg: 'server is set' })
})

module.exports = app
```

Socket.io needs server which is not created in middleware, that's why is taken from firest request to app from `res.connection.server`.

5. Create page `pages/index.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <input v-model="msg">
    <button @click="socket.emit('msg', msg)">send</button>
    <br/>
    <textarea v-model="resps"></textarea>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  head: {
    script: [
      {src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js'},
    ],
  },
  data () {
    return {
      socket: null,
      msg: 'wwJd',
      resps: '',
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$axios.$get('/ws/init')
      .then(resp => {
        this.socket = io()
        this.socket.on('msg', msg => this.resps += `${msg}\n`)
      })
  },
}
</script>
```

6. Run it `npm run dev`;
7. Modify and enjoy :-)