# Nuxt, Express, Sockets can't get connection

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, nuxt.js

Im try in to create a little app and wanted to add websockets to it but im having some issues getting a connection. Im using the nuxt-socket-io and socket io.

```
const socket = require('socket.io')

// Options can be host, port, ioSvc, nspDir:
module.exports = (app) => {
  let server = null
  let io = null
  app.use('/ws', (req, res) => {
    if (!server) {
      server = res.connection.server
      io = socket(server)

      io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('Made socket connection')

        socket.on('msg', (msg) => {
          console.log('Recived: ' + msg)

          setTimeout(() => {
            socket.emit('msg', `Response to: ${msg}`)
          }, 1000)
        })

        socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('disconnected'))
      })
    }

    res.json({ msg: 'server is set' })
  })
}
```

this is being used to create the sockets on the server

and my nuxt-config is

```
['nuxt-socket-io', {
      sockets: [ // Required
        { // At least one entry is required
          name: 'main',
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/ws',
          path: 'ws',
          default: true
        }
      ],
      server: false
    }],
```

then in my .vue file

```
mounted () {
    this.socket = this.$nuxtSocket({
      path: '/api/ws'
    })
  },
  methods: {
    callSocket () {
      console.log('trying to call socket')
      this.socket.emit('msg', 'test message', (resp) => {
        console.log(resp)
        this.resp = resp
      })
    }
  }
```

I get a response from the server

```
{"msg":"server is set"}
```

but I never get to the connection

```
console.log('Made socket connection')
```

but I can't seem to get connected to run any of the emits and i'm not sure why

you can see the full code repo at https://github.com/Chris9540/mappertron
if that will help give you more of an idea of what going on
This is my first time trying to add sockets so I may may done this completely wrong feel free to fork my branch with any alterations you suggest if I'm doing this completely wrong

Answer (score 1):

I've manage to get it working by just using `socket-io` and `socket.io-client` see the I mainly followed this guide https://stackoverflow.com/a/65226573/7805726 see the repo for more details (https://github.com/Chris9540/mappertron) I would still like to get it working with `nuxt-socket-io` but I have sockets so im happy

for my fix I abstracted out some of the app set up to a new file

```
const app = require('express')()
const socket = require('socket.io')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
let server = null
let io = null

app.all('/ws', (req, res) => {
  if (!server) {
    server = res.connection.server
    io = socket(server)

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
      console.log('Made socket connection')

      socket.on('msg', (msg) => {
        console.log('Recived: ' + msg)

        setTimeout(() => {
          socket.emit('msg', `Response to: ${msg}`)
        }, 1000)
      })

      socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('disconnected'))
    })
  }

  res.json({ msg: 'server is set' })
})
app.use(bodyParser.json())
module.exports = app
```

got rid of the nuxt-socket-io configs

and in my vue

```
this.$axios.$get('/api/ws')
      .then((resp) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        this.socket = io()
        this.socket.on('msg', function (msg) {
          console.log('socket responce', msg)
          this.resps += `${msg}\n`
        })
      })
```

and

```
this.socket.emit('msg', JSON.stringify({ id: 1, x: 1, y: 1 }))
```