# Best way to run some code only once on server start in Nuxt.js (and not during build)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

While I wrote [this answer for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65576249/2938364) I came across the problem that I wanted to **execute some code exactly once** in Nuxt.js when the server is started (or while the server is starting).

I thought about writing a module or a plugin, but I did not succeed, since both were executed every time I contacted the server, i.e., every time I made a call to *localhost:3000/myPage*.
Probably I am missing the right module hook or some plugin setting?

Since I could not find any information on this problem in the official documentation, I now came up with a quite ugly solution: I wrote a serverMiddleware that executes some code (the code that should be run only once) and then returns an empty handler - which now adds (little) unnecessary overhead to every request.

**My question:** What would have been the best way to execute some code exactly once on a Nuxt.js server during/after startup, but not during building?

---

*Minimal ugly working example*:

`nuxt.config.js`:

```
export default {
  ...
  serverMiddleware: [ "~/serverMiddleware/run-once.js" ]
  ...
}
```

`~/serverMiddleware/run-once.js`:

```
console.log("Yay, I only run once when the server is started!")
// Since we are a serverMiddleware, we have to return a handler, even if this it does nothing
// I think this is really ugly...
export default function (req, res, next) {
  next()
}
```

---

PS: I saw questions such as [Is it possible for Nuxt JS plugins to only run once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63689739/is-it-possible-for-nuxt-js-plugins-to-only-run-once) but it seems to not answer my question since the `vue-renderer:ssr:prepareContext` nuxt hook also executes every time I send a request to the server.

Also, a module such as the following does not work since it is also executed during `nuxt build` and not only on `nuxt dev` or `nuxt start`:

```
export default function MyModuleThatShouldOnlyRunOnce (_moduleOptions) {
  console.log("I run on 'nuxt dev' and 'nuxt start', but sadly also on 'nuxt build' :(");
}
```

Comment: tried hooks? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/internals-builder

Comment: @Ifaruki Yes, but it seems that I have not found the right hook yet. I do not want to run code during building, but when the server is being started.

Comment: build:before ? this hook?

Comment: @Ifaruki No, since I do _not_ want to execute code during `nuxt build` but only on `nuxt start` or `nuxt dev`. `"build:before"`, as the name suggests, is executed before building.

Comment: Sounds like you want the [`nuxtServerInit` action](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action).

Comment: @tony19: Thanks for the comment, but no, I am looking for a solution to run some code _once on server startup_, not _once per request_.

Comment: `nuxtServerInit` only runs once on the server, and doesn't run per request in my test. How is that happening for you?

Comment: @tony19 I appreciate your help. Yet, I want to be able to run code exactly once on `nuxt start`, i.e., a single time when I start the server. The `nuxtServerInit` method is executed every time when a vuex-store is set up, i.e., every time a user requests the page. This is not my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this topic is still relevant, but you can solve this using a 'ready' hook:

First create a file like this (./hooks/hooks.js):

```js
export default (nuxtConfig) => ({
    ready: () => {
        // Execute your code here
    }
});
```

Then add it to your nuxt.config.js:

```js
import hooks from './hooks/hooks';

export default {

    // Other stuff

    hooks: hooks(this),

    // Other stuff

}
```

Comment: I will have to test this, thank you.
Not exactly relevant anymore, but if I find the time, I'll test it.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger I'm facing a similar problem where I want to load some data into my Nuxt storage (unstorage) likewise exactly only once. How, if at all, did you end up fixing this?

Comment: @Favna Since this was only a hobby project, I ended up using a different technology and cannot give you any more information on this, sorry. I think you could still use my "Minimal ugly working example" that is stated in the question.